# Java. Зачем геттеры и сеттеры для полей public? (кроме проверок)

Tags: java, ооп

7. Есть ли кроме принципов инкапсуляции еще критерии по которым нужно определять необходимость в гетерах и сеттерах или можно и на прямую а полю обратится? И почему я иногда вижу гетеры и сеттеры 
   для публичных полей? **Помимо проверок.** Это понятно... Есть еще причины зачем это может понадобится?

Comment: А что означает загадочная цифра 7 в вашем вопросе?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Имея геттеры и сеттеры , вы предоставляете открытый интерфейс пользователям вашего класса, который не будет зависеть от того, как геттеры и сеттеры реализованы. Это дает гибкость в разработке. Вы можете менять реализацию геттеров и сеттеров, однако код пользователей при этом меняться не будет.

Конечно, следует выбирать что-то одно: либо геттеры и сеттеры, либо открытые поля. Иначе смысл теряется.

Comment: >>Конечно, следует выбирать что-то одно: либо геттеры и сеттеры, либо открытые поля. Иначе смысл теряется.<<

Comment: Вот и я так всегда считал но тут встретил геттеры и сеттеры для открытых полей и удивился, подумал что-то я тут фундаментально недопонимаю...

Comment: @Павел скорее всего вы встетили код разработчика недостаточной квалификации

Comment: @Павел, вариантов почему геттеры и сеттеры встречаются вместе с полем публичным может быть много, но в основном все сводится либо к недостаточной квалификации, как указано выше, либо к недостатку времени, что бы сделать правильно. Например у меня было такое, когда использовал gson библиотеку, для сериализации в json, в интерфейсах были объявлены геттеры / сетеры, но в самом объекте gson позволял указывать анотации только к полям (хотя я все же в итоге отказался просто от gson в пользу jackson)